# draggable popup widget of kivy

Tags: kivy, popup, draggable

I'm trying to make a draggable popup use kivy,i have tried several methods, for instance on_touch_move, dragbehavior. but all of it can't work,so does anybody master can offer some ideas?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior


class DraggableLayout(DragBehavior, FloatLayout):
    pass


class DraggablePopup(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.content = DraggableLayout()


class DraggablePopupApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Create a DraggablePopup instance
        popup = DraggablePopup(size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))

        return popup


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DraggablePopupApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attaching the `DragBehavior` to the content of the `Popup` rather than the `Popup`. Try changing:

```
class DraggablePopup(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.content = DraggableLayout()
```

to:

```
class DraggablePopup(DragBehavior, Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.content = DraggableLayout()

    def _align_center(self, *_args):
        pass
```

The `_align_center()` method overrides the same method in `ModalView`, which keeps the `ModalView` centered in your window. Overriding this method so that it does nothing allows the `Popup` to be dragged.

There are also some properties that the `DragBehavior` requires, and these can be set by adding:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<DraggablePopup>:
    # Define the properties for the DraggablePopup
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    drag_timeout: 10000000
    drag_distance: 0
''')
```

in your python code.

Comment: it's great,it finally work,I'm a green hand on kivy，thank you very much.

Comment: further, i found if use popup.open() rather than return a popup, it can't move again

Comment: The `Popup` class inherits from `ModalView` which is designed to keep itself centered. Redefining the `_align_center()` method of `ModalView`, so that it does nothing,  allows the `Popup` to be dragged.